# RSA Algorithm in C private key

Tags: linux, algorithm, encryption, rsa, private-key

Implement the encryption algorithm RSA. Specifically:

1. Implement an algorithm that converts a message into an integer and the reverse. Suppose messages consist only of characters of the English alphabet.
2. Create two prime numbers p and q size 512 bits. Calculate then N, a public key e and its corresponding private d. With the parameters you create, encrypt and decrypt a message of your choice to check the correctness of your implementation.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "gmp.h"
#define BASE 256  
#ifndef MAXLEN
#define MAXLEN 256
#endif   
void str_int(mpz_t r, char *str);
void int_str(char *str, mpz_t org_str_int);
void eukleidhs(mpz_t a,mpz_t b,mpz_t xx,mpz_t yy); 
gmp_randstate_t stat;
int main()
{
      gmp_randstate_t rand_state;
      gmp_randinit_default(rand_state);
      long sd = 0;
      mpz_t p, q, p1, q1, n, message_int, a, b, temp_p, temp_q, p_1, q_1, f, e, gcd, d, c, m, A, B, C, D, i, ed, ed_m, fl1, fl2, d1, d2;
      mpz_t seed;
      gmp_randinit(stat, GMP_RAND_ALG_LC, 120);
      mpz_init(p);
      mpz_init(q);
      mpz_init(p1);
      mpz_init(q1);
      mpz_init(n);
      mpz_init(p_1);
      mpz_init(q_1);
      mpz_init(f);
      mpz_init(e);
      mpz_init(fl1);
      mpz_init(fl2);
      mpz_init(d1);
      mpz_init(d2);
      mpz_init(gcd);
      mpz_init(d);
      mpz_init(c);
      mpz_init(A);
      mpz_init(m);
      mpz_init(B);
      mpz_init(C);
      mpz_init(D);
      mpz_init(i);
      mpz_init(ed);
      mpz_init(ed_m);
     mpz_init(message_int);
     mpz_init(seed);
      unsigned char message[MAXLEN], out_message[MAXLEN];
      mpz_init(a);
      mpz_init(b);
      mpz_init(temp_p);
      mpz_init(temp_q);
/* (create p  512 BITS)*/
      srand( (unsigned) getpid());
      sd=rand();
      mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
      gmp_randseed(stat, seed);
      srand( (unsigned) getpid());                                 
      mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);                                          
      mpz_urandomb(p1, stat, 512);                                
   /*  (create q 512 BITS*/
 srand( (unsigned) getpid());
 sd=rand();
 mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
gmp_randseed(stat, seed);
srand( (unsigned) getpid());                                 
 mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);                                        
 mpz_urandomb(q1, stat, 512);                             
      int primetest;   
      primetest = mpz_probab_prime_p(p1, 5);
      if (primetest != 0)
      {
            mpz_set(p, p1);
            printf("p= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, p); 
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");
      }
      else
      {
            mpz_nextprime(p, p1);
            printf("p= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, p); 
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");
      }    
      primetest = mpz_probab_prime_p(q1, 5); 
      if (primetest != 0) 
      {
           mpz_set(q, q1);
            printf("q= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, q); 
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");
      }
      else
      {
            mpz_nextprime(q, p);
            printf("q= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, q); 
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n");    
      }    
 /*( n, p-1, q-1, f)*/
      mpz_mul(n, p, q);
      printf("n= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);            // n=p*q
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
      mpz_sub_ui(p_1, p, 1);
      printf("p-1= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, p_1);        // p-1
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");  
      mpz_sub_ui(q_1, q, 1);
      printf("q-1= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, q_1);        // q-1   
      printf("\n");   
      printf("\n");
      mpz_mul(f, p_1, q_1);
      printf("f= "); mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, f);            //f=(p-1)*(q-1)
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
/*( 1<e<f)*/
      sequence1: 
      mpz_urandomb(e, stat, 512);                  
      if ((mpz_cmp_si(e,1)) && (mpz_cmp (e,f)))   
      { 
            mpz_gcd(gcd, e, f);                 
            if (mpz_cmp_si(gcd,1))              
            {
                  printf("To e einai:\n");
                  printf("e= ");
                  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, e);
                  printf("\n");
                  printf("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                  goto sequence1;
            }
      }

      else

      {
            goto sequence1;
      }

/*( d WSTE 1<d<f and e*d= 1 mod f)*/
      mpz_invert(d, e, f);
     printf("To d einai:\n");
      printf("d= ");
      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, d);
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
/*keys)*/
      printf("The public key is :\n");           
      printf("(n,e)= ");
      printf(" (");
      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);
      printf("  ,  ");
      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, e);
      printf(") ");
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("The private key is:\n");          
      printf("d= ");  
      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, d);
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");
      printf("GRAPSE TO MYNHMA SOU(Mexri %d xarakthres) !!!! :", MAXLEN);
        fgets(message, MAXLEN - 1, stdin);  
      str_int(m, message);
      #ifdef HEX
        gmp_printf("TO MHNYMA(%d)  -> %Zx\n\n", strlen(message), m); // EKTTYPWSH MYNHMATOS SE ARITHMO
      #else
        gmp_printf("TO MHNYMA(%d)  -> %Zd\n\n", strlen(message), m);
      #endif  

/*( c = m^e mod n)*/

      mpz_powm(c, m, e, n);
      exit1:
      printf("TO KRYPTOGRAFHMENO KEIMENO EINAI:\n");         
      printf("c= ");
      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, c);
      printf("\n");
      printf("\n");

    mpz_set_ui(m,0);          
/*( m = c^d mod n)*/  
      mpz_powm(m, c, d, n);
      exit2:

      printf("TO APOKRYPTOGRAFHMENO KEIMENO EINAI:\n");          
      printf("m= ");

      mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, m);

      printf("\n");

      printf("\n");


      int_str(out_message, m);

   #ifdef HEX

        gmp_printf("TO APOKRYPTOGRAFHMENO KEIMENO EINAI: %Zd\n            -> %s(%d)\n", m, out_message, strlen(out_message));

      #else

        gmp_printf("TO APOKRYPTOGRAFHMENO KEIMENO EINAI: %Zd\n            -> %s(%d)\n", m, out_message, strlen(out_message));

      #endif


return 0;

}
/* SYNARTHSH METATROPHS STRING SE AKERAIO*/

void str_int(mpz_t r, char *str)

{

      long int str_len, j;

      unsigned char C;



      str_len = strlen(str);

      if(str[str_len - 1] == '\n')

            str[str_len - 1] = '\0';

      str_len = strlen(str);



      mpz_set_ui(r, 0UL);              



      for(j = str_len - 1; j >= 0; j--)           // r = str[str_len - 1] * BASE^(str_len - 1) + ... + str[1] * BASE + str[0]

      {

      C = str[j];



            mpz_mul_ui(r, r, (unsigned long)BASE);           

            mpz_add_ui(r, r, (unsigned long)C);

      }

}


void int_str(char *str, mpz_t org_str_int)

{

      long int str_len, i;

      mpz_t max_int, c_int, str_int;



      mpz_init(max_int);                  //ARXIKOPOIHSH

      mpz_init(c_int);

      mpz_init(str_int);



      mpz_set(str_int, org_str_int);



      mpz_set_ui(max_int, 1UL);          

      for(i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++)

      {

            if(mpz_cmp(str_int, max_int) <= 0)

            {

                  str_len = i;
                break;
            }

            mpz_mul_ui(max_int, max_int, (unsigned long)BASE);
      }

      for(i = 0; i < str_len; i++)        //METATROPH SE GRAMMA

      {
            mpz_mod_ui(c_int, str_int, (unsigned long)BASE);

            mpz_sub(str_int, str_int, c_int);
            mpz_tdiv_q_ui(str_int, str_int, (unsigned long)BASE);
            str[i] = mpz_get_ui(c_int);

      }

      str[str_len] = '\0';

      mpz_clear(max_int);

      mpz_clear(c_int);
      mpz_clear(str_int);

}
/*ALGORITHMOS EUKLEIDH*/

void eukleidhs(mpz_t a,mpz_t b,mpz_t xx,mpz_t yy)

{
      int flag=0;
      mpz_t d,x,y,x1,x2,y1,y2,q,r;
      mpz_t qb,a_qb,temp;
      mpz_t qx1,x2_x1;
      mpz_t qy1,y2_y1;
      mpz_init(x);
      mpz_init(y);
      mpz_init(d);

      if(mpz_cmp(b,a)>0) {

            flag=1;

            mpz_init(temp);

            mpz_set(temp,b);
            mpz_set(b,a);
            mpz_set(a,temp);
            mpz_clear(temp);
      }

      if(mpz_cmp_ui(b,0)==0) {

            mpz_set(d,a);

            mpz_set_ui(x,1);

            mpz_set_ui(y,0);

      }

      else {

           mpz_init(q);
            mpz_init(r);  
            mpz_init(x1);
            mpz_init(x2);

            mpz_init(y1);
            mpz_init(y2);
            mpz_init(qb);
            mpz_init(a_qb);
           mpz_init(qx1);
            mpz_init(qy1);
            mpz_init(x2_x1);    
            mpz_init(y2_y1);
            mpz_set_ui(x2,1);
           mpz_set_ui(x1,0);
            mpz_set_ui(y1,1);
            mpz_set_ui(y2,0);
            while(mpz_cmp_ui(b,0)>0) {
                  mpz_tdiv_q(q,a,b);
                  mpz_mul(qb,q,b);       
                  mpz_sub(a_qb,a,qb);
                  mpz_set(r,a_qb);
                  mpz_mul(qx1,q,x1);           
                  mpz_sub(x2_x1,x2,qx1);
                  mpz_set(x,x2_x1);
                  mpz_mul(qy1,q,y1);           
                  mpz_sub(y2_y1,y2,qy1);
                  mpz_set(y,y2_y1);
                 mpz_set(a,b);  
                  mpz_set(b,r); 
                  mpz_set(x2,x1); 
                  mpz_set(x1,x);
                  mpz_set(y2,y1);
                 mpz_set(y1,y);                                                   
            }
      }
      mpz_set(d,a);
      mpz_set(x,x2);
      mpz_set(y,y2);  
      if(flag==1){
            mpz_set(yy,x);
            mpz_set(xx,y);
      }
      else {
            mpz_set(yy,y);
            mpz_set(xx,x);
      }
      mpz_clear(d);
      mpz_clear(x);
      mpz_clear(y);
      mpz_clear(x1);
      mpz_clear(x2);
      mpz_clear(y1);
      mpz_clear(y2);
      mpz_clear(q);
      mpz_clear(r);
      mpz_clear(qb);
      mpz_clear(a_qb);
      mpz_clear(qx1);
      mpz_clear(x2_x1);
      mpz_clear(qy1);
      mpz_clear(y2_y1);
}
```

I run the program but the private key comes out 0 and i cant find the mistake!

Comment: You have a vast number of blank lines in the code which makes the code unreadable.  You've not shown what your inputs are, or where the values break down.  I've not tracked whether you've initialized each variable that you've declared; there are a bucketful of variables and a bucketful of `mpz_init()` calls, and another bucketful of `mpz_clear()` calls at the end, and I don't know which of those matter and which don't.  You should try making it work with small numbers -- ones which don't need GMP support.  You can then verify the algorithm with built-in types and GMP types in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that you are repeatedly reseeding the system random number generator with the same value, e.g.

```
srand( (unsigned) getpid());
sd=rand();
mpz_set_ui(seed, sd);
gmp_randseed(stat, seed);
```

Don't do this. You end up getting the same random number each time, and it's likely that reusing the same numbers for multiple purposes is giving bad results.